# Fill in a numpy array without creating list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I would like to create a numpy array without creating a list first. 

At the moment I've got this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

dfa = pd.read_csv('csva.csv')
dfb = pd.read_csv('csvb.csv')

pa = np.array(dfa['location'])
pb = np.array(dfb['location'])

ra = [(pa[i+1] - pa[i]) / float(pa[i]) for i in range(9999)]
rb = [(pb[i+1] - pb[i]) / float(pb[i]) for i in range(9999)]

ra = np.array(ra)
rb = np.array(rb)
```

Is there any elegant way to do in one step the last fill in of this np array without creating the list first ?

Thanks

Comment: Few steps might help 1) Post raw data 2) Expected output.

Comment: You could also use `dfa['location'].values` in palce of `np.array(dfa['location'])`

Comment: Wanted to ask same question, but I see now there is no general answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate with vectors in numpy, without the need of lists:

```
ra = (pa[1:] - pa[:-1]) / pa[:-1]
rb = (pb[1:] - pb[:-1]) / pb[:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The title of your question and what you need to do in your specific case are actually two slighly different things.

**To create a numpy array without "casting" a list** (or other iterable) you can use one of the several methods defined by numpy itself that returns array:

- `np.empty`, `np.zeros`, `np.ones`, `np.full` to create arrays of given size with fixed values
- `np.random.*` (where `*` can be various distributions, like normal, uniform, exponential ...), to create arrays of given size with random values

In general, read this: [Array creation routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html)

**In your case**, you already have numpy arrays (`pa` and `pb`) and you don't have to create lists to calculate the new arrays (`ra` and `rb`), you can directly operate on the numpy arrays (which is the entire point of numpy: you can do operations on arrays way faster that would be iterating over each element!). Copied from [@Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29915068/1362167):

```
ra = (pa[1:] - pa[:-1]) / pa[:-1]
rb = (pb[1:] - pb[:-1]) / pb[:-1]
```

This will be **much faster** than you're current implementation, not only because you avoid converting a list to ndarray, but because numpy arrays are order of magnuitude faster for mathematical and batch operations than iteration

Answer (score 0):

> [numpy.zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)
>
> Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with zeros.

or

> [numpy.ones](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html)
>
> Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with ones.

or

> [numpy.empty](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty)
>
> Return a new array of given shape and type, without initializing
>   entries.